# Flexbox fill available space vertically

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Now in a `flexbox` row I can write

```
<div layout="row">
  <div>some content</div>
  <div flex></div> <!-- fills/grows available space -->
  <div>another content</div>
</div>
```

I would like to achieve the same but vertically, like on this picture
[image]
Currently the problem is that the *div* which would need to grow doesn't have any *height* so the two contents are below each other. *I want my second content to be at the bottom of the parent container which has a fixed height!*

I know I could solve this by positioning the second content absolute and `bottom: 0;` but can I achieve this with `flexbox`?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

So you can try this:

1. `flex-direction: column` for the flex container.
2. `flex: 1` for the element that needs to fill the remaining space.

See demo below where the `flexbox` spans the viewport height:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.flex {
  flex: 1;
}
.row, .row > * {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>some content</div>
  <div class="flex">This fills the available space</div>
  <!-- fills/grows available space -->
  <div>another content</div>
</div>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Lovely! Thank you so much. This was killing me since the last hour.

Comment: Thank you, i was not adding height to the parent

Answer (score 21):

You just need to use `flex-direction: column` on parent and `flex: 1` on middle div.

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.row > div:not(.flex) {
  background: #676EE0;
}
.flex {
  flex: 1;
  background: #67E079;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>some content</div>
  <div class="flex"></div>
  <!-- fills/grows available space -->
  <div>another content</div>
</div>
```