# How can I make a <row> vertically span the viewport's entire height?

Tags: html, css

If I have the following HTML code,

```
<row>
    <column width="10%">
    <column width="80%"><img />
    <column width="10%">
</row>
```

how can I make the row span the entire height of the view port (in vertical)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flexbox fill available space vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020921/flexbox-fill-available-space-vertically)

Answer (score 1):

> **Explanation -**

**vh** - Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport

**viewport** - the browser window size.

**For eg:**
*If the viewport is 50cm high, 1vh = 0.5cm.*

> **Solution to your issue -**

```
row {
    height: 100vh;
}
```