# How can a "middle" div be scrollable, and still respond similar to "chat" like UI?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a simple HTML/CSS based chat UI, where there are three vertical divs: *Header*, *Chats*, and *Send Bar*.

[image]

If I have three `div`s, how can I the middle div be the full "middle" height, and still be scrollable for scrolling messages? I can do this if I set the send bar div to a static height, but if I want it to be growable, that approach doesn't work.

*Does anyone know how to use css to make a responsive chat-like UI such that the middle content is scrollable and the send bar content is growable?*

I don't think it matters, but this is a **React** app.

Here is a code example of the issues I am seeing: (a) the lower div isn't sticky to the view, and (b), the middle div isn't scrollable.

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lv9dw3r1/) and snippet:

```css
.wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
 height: 10px;
 background: yellow;
}

.bottom {
 background: gray;
}

.middle {
 background: red;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top">

  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>
    some content
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should provide code snippets not screenshots.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020921/flexbox-fill-available-space-vertically/

Comment: see changes to your code: https://jsfiddle.net/gnfvxmu4/ based on the above question...

Comment: @kukkuz That did it. Post that in an answer, and I'll happily accept. Looks like I was overlooking the `overflow: auto`. Thank you!

Comment: Well, the other one doesn't have the `overflow: auto`, which was the culprit for having the middle be scrollable in this case. So it doesn't actually answer my question as-is. However, yes, I agree they are both related.

Comment: have added answer with detailed explanation, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolute *positioning* for your `wrapper` is not really necessary here. Also specifying `height: 100%` for the `middle` does not *fill the remaining space left by the `top` and the `middle`.

- set the height of you flexbox to the viewport height so that the flexbox knows the height it needs to stretch to,
- add `flex: 1` to the middle section to *fill the remaining space* (You can refer [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020921/flexbox-fill-available-space-vertically/) to see a simple demo of this),
- add `overflow: auto` to the `middle` section - note that `overflow` value other than visible or resetting `min-height` to zero will override the default `min-height: auto` for a column flexbox.  - read more details here: [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size)
  (see some examples of this behavior [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277368/flexbox-affects-overflow-wrap-behavior/52278099#52278099) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303538/flexbox-resize-and-scrollable-overflow/55303600#55303600).)
- also add `flex: 0 0 auto` to `bottom` element so that in edge cases we can ensure that the it doesn't grow or shrink in any case.

See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /* reset default body margin */
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh; /* full viewport height */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  background: yellow;
}

.bottom {
  background: gray;
  flex: 0 0 auto; /* don't grow or shrink in any case */
}

.middle {
  background: red;
  flex: 1; /* fill the remaining space */
  min-height: 0; /* optional */
  overflow: auto; /* overflow if exceeds available space */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    <p>
     Test
    </p>
    
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>
    some content
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using flexbox:

```css
#flexbox_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px -2px #999;
  height: 90%;
}

.flex_item {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.middle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexbox_container">
  <div class="flex_item">
    Item</div>
  <div class="flex_item middle">
    <p>item</p>
    <p>item</p>
    <p>item</p>
    <p>item</p>
    <p>item</p>
    <p>item</p>
    <p>item</p>
    <p>item</p>
    <p>item</p>
    <p>item</p>
    <p>item</p>
    <p>item</p>
    <p>item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex_item">Item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```css
.wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
 height: 10px;
 background: yellow;
}

.bottom {
 background: gray;
}

.middle {
 background: red;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top">

  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <p>
    some content
    </p>
        <p>
    some content
    </p>
        <p>
    some content
    </p>
        <p>
    some content
    </p>
        <p>
    some content
    </p>
        <p>
    some content
    </p>
        <p>
    some content
    </p>
            <p>
    some content
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>
    some content
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that the middle div isn't scrollable, nor is the bottom div static. Which are the two problems I am trying to solve. I made a jsfiddle to showcase the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/Lv9dw3r1/

Comment: just add 'overflow-y: auto;' into the css. I edited the snippet.