# Make div use all the remaining height of the screen

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to make the **.content** div use the remaining screen height.
I don´t know what´s the height of **.header** - *I can´t use calc(100vh - headerHeight)*

HTML structure

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="header">header</div>
        <div class="content">content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Tried with

```
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

using 100vh didn´t work because it generated some vertical scroll (with the height of the **.header**)

```
.content {
    height: 100vh
}
```

it should look like this

```
+-------------------------------+
|            header             |
+-------------------------------+
|                               |
|                               |
|            content            |
|                               |
|                               |
+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020921/

Answer (score 1):

Set the `<body>` element as your flex container.
Then you can set `.content` so it's able to grow.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
```

For reference, see [Basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would consider the following code.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: khaki;
  height: 100%;
}

.wraper {
  height: 100vh;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="wraper">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This seems similar the OP's attempt using `100vh`, but it wasn't satisfactory because it "generated some vertical scroll (with the height of the .header)".

Comment: correct. if .content is Is higher than 100vh it will hide the .header