# set height relative to fixed element

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox, responsive

I have this code where i have two fixed navbars at the top and bottom.

I want the box to be of the size between the two navbars and to change it with the size of the nav changing with the size of the screen to always see the margin and the text of the cards.

```css
body, html{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
  
.nav{
  padding:5px;
  margin:0;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#84a9ca;
  font-size:5vh;
}
.bas{
  opacity:0.5;
  bottom:0;
}
.box{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#6ec6e1;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  
}
.element{
  background-color:#488a45;
  width:100px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<!--change with the size of the window-->
<div class="nav haut">nav</div>
  <!--take all the place but want it to be just between the navs-->
  <div class="box">
    <!--text and margin hidden by the nav-->
    <div class="element">element</div>
    <div class="element">element</div>
    <div class="element">element</div>
  </div>
<!--transparent to show what's behind-->
<div class="nav bas">nav</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest looking at "Grid layout", it will likely make you life easier.

Comment: This is what I want:https://framapic.org/mQr3u0HDrUjG/iVb2KyO5MB3n.png but responsive

Comment: I think you got your question answered here: [Flexbox fill available space vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40021077/3636917)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` on the body too, and remove the fixed position:

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden; 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #84a9ca;
  font-size: 5vh;
}

.bas {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #6ec6e1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.element {
  background-color: #488a45;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!--change with the size of the window-->
<div class="nav haut">nav</div>
<!--take all the place but want it to be just between the navs-->
<div class="box">
  <!--text and margin hidden by the nav-->
  <div class="element">element</div>
  <div class="element">element</div>
  <div class="element">element</div>
</div>
<!--transparent to show what's behind-->
<div class="nav bas">nav</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Four steps:

- Fix the `nav haut` at `top: 0` and the `nav bas` at `bottom: 0`
- Give `nav haut` and `nav bas` a `height` and `line-height` of `32px`
- Give `.box` a `margin-top` of `32px`
- Give `.box` a `height` of `calc(100vh - 64px)`

This means that `.box` will always start directly beneath `nav haut` and will have the height of the entire page, minus the heights of `nav haut` and `nav bas`.

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
  
.nav{
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #84a9ca;
}

.haut{
  top:0;
}

.bas{
  bottom:0;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 64px);
  margin-top: 32px;
  background-color: #6ec6e1;
}

.element{
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #488a45;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav haut">nav</div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="element">element</div>
    <div class="element">element</div>
    <div class="element">element</div>
  </div>
<div class="nav bas">nav</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code in element css class

```
 .element {
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 padding: 0px;
 }
```